# Oracle spatial: how should I select list of polygon points from sdo_geometry type?

Tags: oracle, polygon, spatial

I put a record into my table

```
INSERT INTO S_DS " +
            "values " +
            "(S_DS_SEQ.nextval, " +
            "SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, null, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1,1003,1), " +
            "sdo_ordinate_array("+addition+")))
```

where "addition" is a string of coord'pairs like "(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)"
Now i need to take these points by query.
How can I do that?
I googled alot but no results so far -_-

---

update:

found by myself: ordinates can be queried by
    Select table.attribute_name.**sdo_ordinates** from tableName;

then extracted from your ResultSet with casting to BigDecimal[]

```
(BigDecimal[])resultset.getArray("S_ARR").getArray()
```